# Comprehensive book that covers the basics of Complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, book-recommendation, complex-integration

I am supposed to Graduate from Mathematics this year, but the course complex analysis is keeping me behind as I failed to pass the course in my final year.

I have downloaded several materials on complex analysis but I still don't have what I really need.

It is imminent I pass the course this year if I have to graduate. More than passing the course I want to have an A in the course as I believe I can but in other to do that I would like for a recommendation from a professional on a comprehensive book that covers pretty much everything on complex analysis and more importantly the following topics.

> 1. Introduction to complex numbers
> 2. Functions of Complex Variables
> 3. Power series
> 4. Complex integration
> 5. Cauchy's theorem and its consequences
> 6. Calculus of Residues
> 7. Complex Sequences

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i had [Levinson and Redheffer](https://books.google.com/books/about/Complex_variables.html?id=x5knAQAAIAAJ) back in them olden days.  now there are several online books that are pdf.

Comment: Schaum's also has a book about exercises in your subject. I found that book particularly helpful for problems regarding Residue theorem (Cauchy) for evaluating integrals

Comment: I can't recommend Hilary Priestly's book high enough

Comment: Brown and Churchill is the best one.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following book to you :

It is easy to read ,contains the above topics and is particularly suitable for suitable for self-study as you will find most of the exercises with hints/solutions at the back of the chapter.

[Joseph_Bak,_Donald_J._Newman]_Complex_Analysis